# travis CI pear PHP dependency doesn't get installed

Tags: php, pear, travis-ci

I've got a [Python project at github](https://github.com/ducin/pycached), which I test on travis-ci.org. There is a small client in PHP that I use for testing it (it should be a cross-language tool).

Recently I changed the username in my github repo, committed it and it triggered the travis build. It failed, because of a PHP/pear error:

```
The command "sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

You can see the build matrix below:

- https://travis-ci.org/ducin/pycached/builds/65778230
- https://travis-ci.org/ducin/pycached/jobs/65778231
- https://travis-ci.org/ducin/pycached/jobs/65778232

The previous commit was submitted and tested on travis last year and everything was ok, the `pear channel-discover` command worked. I changed nothing but the github username, which is not a problem for sure, so I expect that certain service became unavailable since then.

Please point me out what is wrong with my build and how can I make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.phpunit.de has been closed down in favour of using phar files or installing phpunit via composer. You should uninstall the PEAR version of phpunit and install it from another source.

https://thephp.cc/news/2015/01/phpunit-migration-from-pear-to-phar

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But did you notice, that I'm asking about a travis CI build? Besides, what exactly should I do? I'm not familiar with neither phar nor composer...

Comment: i do not know travisci, but you can try just composer install phpunit/phpunit

Comment: Please look at this: https://travis-ci.org/ducin/pycached/jobs/68402095. `composer install phpunit/phpunit` doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work either. I gave 6 shots at travis-ci (https://travis-ci.org/ducin/pycached/builds), none of them work, neither `composer require phpunit/phpunit`. Won't accept that one.

Comment: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/ it doesnt seem like you need to install phpunit in travis, seems like only using script: phpunit in your travis build should be enough?